# How do I sort by subcategories of time using the updated_at tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

`@todo = Todo.where(done:true,user:current_user.email).where("updated_at >= ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)`

So this is an example of a call I'm making. Now how can I sort by subcategories of time? Eg. Grab all the entries from six days ago, all the entries from five days ago, and perhaps even from every week this month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example of querying a date range.  It'll find all tasks from one week ago to today.

```
@todo = Todo.where(done: true, 
                   user: current_user.email,
                   updated_at: 1.week.ago..Date.today)
```

Comment: Was about to close this question - asked it without researching properly. thanks though.